# From points to raster - how do I set a gaussian function with a cutoff

Tags: r, rasterization, terra

### Context

> [SMAP's user guide](https://salinity.oceansciences.org/docs/JPL_SMAP-SSS-UsersGuide.pdf) states:
> "*We use Gaussian weighting to interpolate the L2B estimates onto the map grid with a search radius of approx. 45 km and a half-power radius of 30 km.*".

### Problem

This is something I would like to achieve in R, but I don't know how to code this!

```
require(terra)
require(sf)
```

So if I define a global raster like theirs :

```
Frame_SMAP = rast(nrows=180, ncols=360, nlyrs=1, xmin=-180, xmax=180, 
                  ymin=-90, ymax=90, crs="epsg:4326", resolution=.25)
```

and a random set of observations that I want to rasterize (using two variables to facilitate generalization) :

```
Obs_SMAP = data.frame(
  x = runif(n = 1000,min = -180, max=180),
  y = runif(n = 1000,min = -90, max=90),
  z1 = runif(n = 1000,min = 0, max=100),
  z2 = runif(n = 1000,min = 0, max=100) 
)
```

**How can I transfer these `Obs_SMAP` onto `Frame_SMAP` using a Gaussian weighting with search radius of 45 km and a half-power radius of 30 km?**

---

---

### Efforts

I found a lead towards something like a solution using terra::rasterizeWin, but it's not quite it...

```
Obs_SMAP_sf <- st_as_sf(x = Obs_SMAP , coords = c("x", "y")) 
Obs_SMAP_sp <- as(Obs_SMAP_sf, "Spatial")
Obs_SMAP_v <- vect(Obs_SMAP_sp)

 
x_WIN <- rast(sapply(names(Obs_SMAP_v), function(x) rasterizeWin(Obs_SMAP_v, Frame_SMAP, field = x, win='circle',pars=.25,fun='mean')))
```

---

Comment: What interpolation model did they use? With Gaussian weighting and a specified power function, it sounds somewhat like an IDW. All the weighting is doing is creating a spatial die-off following a normal, rather then flat, distribution. The `interp::interp` function allows for specifying a Gaussian process. Using `terra::interpolate` you can pass about any appropriate model function making it quite flexible.

Comment: It sounds like a truncated gaussian? Consider everything beyond 45km as zero-weighted and within that use a gaussian with standard deviation such that the weight is 0.5 at 30km? That's an sd of 25.4778 approximately... (via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum)

Comment: If I use focalMat of type "Gauss" and distance 45km, how can I pass the sd=25.4778 ?