# How do I reproject without an EPSG code?

Tags: r, sf, proj

I have a set of points that I need to project, but can't find the EPSG code.
(EPSG have made it so easy I never had to work with non-built-in codes..)

```
library(sf)
```

> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

```
sfc = st_sfc(st_point(c(0,0)), st_point(c(1,1)))
sf = st_sf(a = 1:2, geom = sfc)
st_crs(sf) = 4326

st_transform(sf, ####)
```

How do I use the st_transform function with [The SOM projection](https://proj4.org/en/latest/operations/projections/som.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a "proj" string in R with any of the PROJ parameters, including the projection type and then feed that to `st_transform`. For example:

```
> p = "+proj=som +inc_angle=98.303820000243860022 +ps_rev=0.06866666666666667 +asc_lon=64.412896137498847793"
```

And then:

```
> st_transform(sf, p)
```

But I get...

```
Error: crs not found: is it missing?
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_crs_from_input(x) :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument): Unknown projection
```

Because I suspect `som` is a recent addition to PROJ and I've a older PROJ? Let's see:

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

and I don't see it in the docs for 8.2 https://proj.org/en/8.2/operations/projections/index.html

To show the point, here's a stereographic projection with custom parameters via PROJ string:

```
> p = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=75"
> st_transform(sf, p)
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: -12497050 xmax: 214354.8 ymax: -12280380
Projected CRS: +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=75
  a                       geom
1 1        POINT (0 -12497046)
2 2 POINT (214354.8 -12280377)
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the PROJ parameters in the right form to use with `sf`. I also appreciate the example of the stereo projection.

As for the `SOM`, well, this is a mystery...

I should have pointed out that the SOM projection is used to exploit [Landsat](https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/about/space-oblique-mercator-projection/
) and other orbiting platforms, so nothing recent really. I will look at the different forums on Earth Observation and update if I find anything.

Comment: Whats the mystery? Is your problem now finding the correct parameters for a SOM projection for some data you have? If you have a latest version of PROJ you can use it in the same way I've shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just installed the latest version of `PROJ` and R returns the same error message you printed above (_unknown projection_).

Comment: To provide context, I am currently addressing a specific issue, and the question presented here is a subset of a broader inquiry discussed in a separate [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474173/from-points-to-raster-how-do-i-set-a-gaussian-function-with-a-cutoff?).

Comment: It would be useful information if you edited the question and added the version string produced by `library(sf)`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My question was edited with the version string for sf. 
Would you recommend updating GEO, GDAL and PROJ ?

Comment: If your PROJ version supports the som transform then my example with som should work for you.  Does it? Have you tried? Can you edit your question, or maybe post a new one, to show this?

Comment: Thank you for your message. As mentioned earlier, I'm encountering the same error message that you've described. I claimed to have the latest PROJ version; however, I now realize that may not be the case. Unfortunately, I am unsure of the process to upgrade PROJ on my mac.

Comment: According to the release notes SOM was added in 9.2.0, so you need at least that. If that (or newer) version is not available via packages for your platform then you may need to get the source code, build it, and then build the `sf` package and link. This *definitely* should be another question (and may already have been asked! Search first!)

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion. The new question was posted here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474823/r-sf-package-upgrade-proj