# R sf package - upgrade PROJ

Tags: r, sf, proj

Using Rstudio, I need a projection that is not available in the PROJ version I have (see [that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474322/how-do-i-reproject-without-an-epsg-code/) question).

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

I would like to upgrade PROJ.

I tried through the terminal

```
> xcode-select --install
> brew install proj
> brew --prefix proj
```

> /opt/homebrew/opt/proj

but of course, after restarting Rstudio `sf` still shows PROJ 9.1.0, since I don't know how to recompile with that more recent PROJ.

**Any clue how to tell `sf` to upgrade PROJ version ?**

---

R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 14.2.1

Comment: What about recompiling {sf}? I mean, just run `install.package(... , type="source")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried with source but encountered:


    >checking GDAL: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.8.3_1/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... no
    >checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... no
`

File _pcs.csv_ doesn't exist on my computer, and I don't know how to link _PROJ_.